# JavaScript jQuery Regexp while

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Do Regular expression have power to live format 
entering string in this format  `( /^\d{3}\-?\d{1,13}\-\d{2}$/ )`. By that I mean , when I type ( 123 ) , he automatic put  (123-).

I use jQuery function which I listed it in the example below.

--Point is when user what to type his bank account I want to live format it. 

---Can this job be finished by Regexp ---

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="radi" />
```

JavaScript:

```
    //This work on every typed character
    $("#radi").bind('input', function(event) {

        $("#radi").bankPlug('change', $(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: Svice, regex (allone) is not sufficient for this kind of tasks. You have to check/replace char by char, while user typing, and then change field value... seems simple, but, you have to think about copy/paste into text field(s), too...make your life easier: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ Maybe this could help you... ;)

Comment: tnx alot... Because i make this code work but i use regEx only for validateing .. i made 3 simple functions to insert ( - ) and other things... and i saw its prity big code like 200 lines ...and i think its pretty big code for this kind of job .. Now i will look what you send to me XD best Rigarts

Comment: DO anyone have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keypress` function followed by the `replace` function. `replace` can take a function as a second parameter. Here's one possible way to do it.

```js
$("input").on("keypress", function(e) {
    var inputNum = $(this).val();
    if (e.keyCode != 45 && (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\d{3}/, function(n) {       
        return (/\d{3}-/).test(inputNum) ? n : n + "-" 
    })); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" />
```

Comment: Will this patern work for makeing and formating input

123-123123-12 ? Can i modify every single part of this ?
I am new to regex and i dont understend it well do you have some tutorial to link me ? or can you make code snip which work?